# How can I define a 3d-body through different views?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

In one of the maths blogs I follow I stumbled upon the [following question](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2014/03/15/shape-in-three-dimensions/):

The bottom, side, and front views of an object are shown below:
[image]

How would the object look in three dimensions?

**My question**
Is it possible to use these views and construct a 3d body out of them that you can then turn in space with Mathematica?

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort to solve the problem in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Some pretty good (if advanced) stuff by Michael Trott [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/08/15/even-more-formulas-for-everything-from-filled-algebraic-curves-to-the-twitter-bird-the-american-flag-chocolate-easter-bunnies-and-the-superman-solid/)

Comment: @Artes: This is indeed true. The challenge for me is that I normally don't use Mathematica for graphics stuff and thought this a good opportunity to get a cold start. To cut a long story short: I don't have a clue where to start but obviously the task is not so trivial after all... what a pity, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't think the provided constraints are sufficent to fully determine the shape, but a shape that is consistent with them is found easily. It is a stack of ellipses with major axis determined by the width of the rectangle and the minor axis (at every height) determined by the triangle. With this information you should be able to build the shape using `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Phi]], (1 - h) Sin[\[Phi]], 2 h}, {\[Phi], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {h, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 0}]

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Thank you, Mathematica says: "Syntax::sntxf: "{" cannot be followed by "[Phi],0,2[Pi]}".", "Syntax::tsntxi: "[Phi]" is incomplete; more input is needed." and "Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed ." - Why don't you form an answer with the corrected command - I would vote for it!

Comment: Note carefully that the problem as you have posed it is very far from having a complete solution. This is showcased by the two answers already present, but you could also e.g. punch a diagonal hole in both of them without changing the projections. In general, you'll need a view from an infinity of angles. This isn't quite a tomography problem, but you may find the spirit of the [Radon transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) useful to read about.

Comment: Just add a backslash before [Phi]. The stupid StackExchange comment processor stripped it.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: ...and also before [Pi] I guess - but yes, now it works - great, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say we have the following 3 shapes.

An isosceles triangle with base and height $(b, h)$ centered at $(x_0,z_0)$,

The shape is given by 3 equations:

$$z > z_0- h/2$$
$$ z < 2 h /b (x- (x_0-b/2)) +(z_0 -h/2)  $$
$$ z < -( 2 h /b (x- (x_0-b/2))) -2 h -(z_0 -h/2)  $$

with a rectangle with width and height  set by the triangle $(b,h)$ and centered at $(y_0,z_0)$
with the following equations:

$$ y_0-b/2<y<y_0 +b/2 $$
$$ z_0 -h/2<z<z_0 +h/2 $$

And a disk with center and radius given by  $((x_0,y_0),b/2)$ with its equation given by

$$ (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 < (b/2)^2 $$

We can then simply place these equations in `RegionPlot3D`
Using the center as:

```
{cx,cy,cz}= {0.5,0.5,0.5};
```

and the base and height of the triangle to be

```
{b,h}={1,1};
```

We obtain the following result

```
RegionPlot3D[(x - cx)^2 + (y - cx)^2 < (b/2)^2 && 
(z > cz - h/2 && (z < (2 h/b (x - (cx - b/2) )) + (cz - h/2) && 
  z < -(2 h/b (x - (cx - b/2)) - 2*h - (cz - h/2))))&&(
  cy-b/2<y<cy+b/2 &&cz-h/2<z<cz+h/2), 
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100];
```

[image]

This should allow you to easily check other possible solutions, if they exist

Comment: nice clear answer +1: more thoughtful than my impulse :)...also proves not unique as many commenters have observed

Comment: When I use it as it stands I get nothing and when I take the last semicolon away I get an empty cube?!? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @vonjd I fixed a typo in the mathematica equation, I had the radius for the circle part as r, instead of b/2, so it wasn't defined. If you find any more mistakes let me know.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you, great work!

Answer (score 12):

I post this as for this particular "puzzle" there is a straightforward approach. However, as has been commented some evidence of attempt is the norm.

```
triang[x_, y_] := {{x, 0, 1}, {x, -y, 0}, {x, y, 0}}
```

Now visualizing for this particular isoceles triangle.

```
Graphics3D[{Polygon[
   Table[triang[j, Sqrt[1 - j^2]], {j, -1, 1, 0.005}]], 
  Polygon[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t], -1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi , 0.001}]], 
  Polygon[{{2, -1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -2, 0}, {1, -2, 0}, {1, -2, 1}, {-1, -2, 1}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: That's just... bad-ass work! +!

Comment: @rasher very kind: inspired by art gallery: (https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/1932283_10202728571109134_314649270_n.jpg) this scuplture was made with Staedtler pencils.

Comment: nice!  It is important to note the solution is certainly not unique.  Indeed we could just combine the three polygons and get those silhouettes.

Comment: @george2079 yes...just the solution that sprang to mind...could not resist posting it

Comment: Nice work! Seems like `SphericalRegion -> True` could do some magic though...

Comment: @IstvanZachar...thank you...did it on fly...agree SphericalRegion would less distorted rotations...may redo when have time

Comment: Here's a smooth plot of what I think is the same object: `ContourPlot3D[x^2 + (y/(1 - z))^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]` http://i.stack.imgur.com/CIqpO.png

Comment: @RahulNarain thanks! Look forward to playing with parametrized surface/solid if and when time permits...my post a bit simplistic but enjoying the commentary